# Custom Cell not displaying in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Did a bunch of google searches over the last few hours about this topic and haven't found a real solution for it.

I have an app where I'd like the user data to show in a table . But once we log in the data doesn't show in the table view, and my console prints 0 rows returned.

Here's the UsersViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


  @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var user = [User]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        retrieveUsers()
    }

    func retrieveUsers() {
     let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
     ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
          guard let users = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] else {return}
            self.user.removeAll()
            for (_, val) in users{
                if let uid = val.value(forKey: "uid") as? String {
                    if uid != FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid{
                        let userToShow = User()
                        if let fullName = val.value(forKey: "full name") as? String, let imagePath = val.value(forKey: "urlToImage") as? String {
                            userToShow.fullName = fullName
                            userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                            userToShow.userID = uid
                            self.user.append(userToShow)
                      }
                    }
                }    
            }
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self.tableview.reloadData()
          }
        })
      ref.removeAllObservers()
    }

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "USERCell", for: indexPath) as! USERCell

    cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
    return cell
  }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     print("\(user.count)")
     return user.count
  }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let key = ref.child("users").childByAutoId().key

        var isFollower = false

        ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                for (ke, value) in following {
                    if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                        isFollower = true

                        ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following/\(ke)").removeValue()
                        ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).child("followers/\(ke)").removeValue()

                        self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
                    }
                }
            }
            if !isFollower {
                let following = ["following/\(key)" : self.user[indexPath.row].userID]
                let followers = ["followers/\(key)" : uid]

                ref.child("users").child(uid).updateChildValues(following)
                ref.child("users").child(self.user[indexPath.row].userID).updateChildValues(followers)

                self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func checkFollowing(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

        ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                for (_, value) in following {
                    if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
                        self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()

    }

    @IBAction func composePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func menuPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!){
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I also have the cell info :

```
import UIKit

class USERCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var userImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!

    var userID: String!

}
```

And the User object :

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

    var userID: String!
    var fullName: String!
    var imagePath: String!

}
```

Let me know. BTW, I have set my id's properly, and linked all of the outlets, etc.

EDIT : Logs -- looks my my variables arent taking any values :

```
> > objc[14259]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both
> > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
> > (0x11a4d6998) and
> > /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
> > (0x11a255880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:10.301 avenir-design-app[14259:575161] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics
> > setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the
> > default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set
> > the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the
> > Info.plist
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:15.526 avenir-design-app[14259:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:15.526 avenir-design-app[14259:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following
> > application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see
> > )
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:15.529 avenir-design-app[14259:] 
> 
> <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App
> > Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag
> > FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:16.240 avenir-design-app[14259] <Notice> [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:16.457: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote
> > notification handlers. To disable add
> > "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:16.458: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:17.332: <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:17.965: <FIRMessaging/WARNING> FIRMessaging AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote
> > notification receiver handlers. Add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled"
> > to your Info.plist and set it to NO
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:30.608 avenir-design-app[14259:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:33.153296 avenir-design-app[14259:575161] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
> > path is
> > /Users/IAMPRAgency/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/473CBD98-C9EA-411C-A167-A507936E8443/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:33.311040 avenir-design-app[14259:575161] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:36.119894 avenir-design-app[14259:575161] [Common] _BSMachError: port 8f07; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14)
> > "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
> >     2017-03-12 21:51:36.120561 avenir-design-app[14259:575161] [Common] _BSMachError: port 8f07; (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable
> > to deallocate send right"
> >     0
> >     0
> >     0
> >     0
```

Comment: Is the class of the custom cell set to `USERCell` in the storyboard?

Comment: is your `if-condition` in retrieve users func met ? Just to make sure that you actually are getting data to display.

Comment: You've got far too much code that just assumes that everything will succeed.  What happens if the query fails?  What happens if it returns something other than `[String: AnyObject]`?  What happens if there aren't any users?  What happens if there's no `uid` key? What happens if the `uid` key doesn't match what you're expecting? What happens if there's no `full name` key? In all of these cases, you silently fail.  You should at the *very least* log a message so that you know what's going on.  Your problem could be any of those and you have no way of knowing because you're ignoring all problems.

Comment: @vadian yes, it is in there.

Comment: @Priyal I will have to log it but it seems so.

Comment: @Jim How would I go about this? Just add prints at inside all the functions?

Comment: @DavidAvenir you need to check if you are actually getting the data. to debug you can either put a breakpoint and check if the value exists or you can use print function, either will serve the purpose.

Comment: @Priyal Here's the log with print statements, it seems my cell + other variables aren't taking any values - see above edit

Comment: @DavidAvenir can't see your edit.

Comment: @Priyal its there now.

Comment: @DavidAvenir Join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55234/discuss-http-stackoverflow-com-questions-42752291-custom-cell-not-displaying-in

Comment: @Priyal wont let me type anything, I just joined SO today.

Comment: ok. I gave you writes. But I guess its not working. Anyways.. I figure that out, Till then check your retrieveUsers func step by step to see where is the fault and where you condition fails.